# close connection after asynchronous HTTP call

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, asynchronous

I want to know if using asynchronous HTTP request, using jquery and requesting a php file that connect to database you need to close `mysqli_close($connection)` the connection after the query?

Comment: You can explicitly close it, and it certainly is good style. However php will automatically shutdown all resources like open connections upon script termination, so you do not have to.

Comment: Not that the mysql extension has been deprecated for awhile, in large part due to the commonality SQL injection vulnerabilities. PDO or mysqli should be used instead.

Comment: yes @outis actualli i use mysqli but i forgot to write it here, edited :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good practice to do so, but when the request ends the database connection is released automatically, so I wouldn't worry about it.

As far as PHP cares an AJAX call is the same as any other, so the same rules apply to a standard page as do to AJAX calls.

Comment: ok perfect, thanks a lot, so using asynchronous calls closing the connection or not it's the same.

Comment: @darkmago yep, the PHP lifecycle is the same regardless

Answer (score 1):

PHP should automatically close connections and free any other resources, taken by script. But a good manner is to close connections explicitly.